# CSS image wipes animation

Tags: webkit, css

From CSS's trick image wipe >>> http://css-tricks.com/webkit-image-wipes/

I have tried the technique above but with no success only when I use :

```
<div><span id="image"></span></div>
```

instead of

```
<div><img src="" /></div>
```

Has anyone ever tried this before? Is there a workaround?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `span` tag is not closed. You've written `</span` instead of `</span>`

**Edit**
check this 
http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/jqacs/5/

i am use color instead of image because they are not working but it's doesn't matter.

**Changes**
i remove `position:absolute` & `z-index`  from span id's `tunnel_mask1 & tunnel1` .So, in span i given `display:block` .

***Note:*** if it necessary to give `position:absolute` to your span id then give animation properties in `#tunnel1` instead of div:nthchild(2)*